# SQL query with JOIN verification needed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following tables and need to run a query on them.

**Teacher:**

```
teacher_code
initial
name
```

**Student:**

```
stud_no
initial
insertions
name
birth_date
address
city
class_code
```

**Class:**

```
class_code
classname
Module:
module_code
modulename
```

**Teacher_module:**

```
teacher_code
module_code
class_code
```

**Grade:**

```
stud_no
module_code
date
grade
```

The queries I need to write is the following.

**Which subjects (subject names) does J. Doe not teach?**

And this is what I was able to come up with:

```
SELECT t.Initial, t.name, m.modulename
FROM Teacher AS t
   NATURAL JOIN
      Module AS m
   NATURAL JOIN
      Teacher_module AS tm
   ON 
      t.teacher_code = tm.teacher_code
WHERE t.Initial <> 'J' 
   AND
      t.name <> 'Doe'
```

Is this query correct?.....  I'm not able to test this because I'm doing it on a paper and have no example dB to test.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can tell just by looking at it that it doesn't answer the question.  The query that does would have a `left join`, `not in`, or `not exists` in it.

Comment: What is preventing you from having an example DB?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ enables you to test queries against relational DBs, without having one installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it "subject" is a synonym for module.  Your WHERE clause is selecting teachers that are not J or Doe, not the modules J Doe does not teach.  It will be something like this:

Quick attempt

```
SELECT m.modulename
FROM Module m
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM teacher_Module tm
  INNER JOIN Teacher t 
      ON t.teacher_code = tm.teacher_code t.Initial = 'J' AND t.name = 'Doe'
  WHERE tm.module_code = m.module_code )
```

You could also use a left join to teacher_Module and Teacher and then check for tm.module_code IS NULL.